# I have written this code but it is not showing any outputs. Why is this happening?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have written this code but I am completely not sure the way I did is correct. Is there anyone that can give me some guidance?

- Create a variable named `numbers` and assign an empty array to it.
- Using a for-loop and the `Array.push()` method, insert the numbers `0` to `9` into the array you named numbers.
- Test that you used the `Array.push()` method correctly by console logging the first item in the array.
- Console log the last item in the array.
- Create another variable named `car` and assign an empty object to it.
- Give the object a property called `colour` and assign it the value of `"black"`.

```js
var numbers = [];

for (var i=0; i < 10; i++){
    numbers.push(i);

console.log(i[1])
console.log(i[9])

}

var car = {};
```

Comment: Jackie Lau, if you are satisfied with my answer, please mark it as accepted on the left side from my answer. Or write some feedback please.

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = [];

for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    numbers.push(i)
}

console.log(numbers[0]);

var lastIndex = numbers.length - 1;

console.log(numbers[lastIndex]);

var car = {};
car.colour = 'black';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have pushed numbers to an array `numbers`, but after this you have mixed up variables `numbers` and `i`. Variable `i` is not an array. Except this your `console.log` is in the `for` loop and this is mistake too.

I have corrected your code:

```js
var numbers = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    numbers.push(i);
}

console.log(numbers[1]); //1
console.log(numbers[9]); //9

var car = {};
car.colour = 'black';
console.log(car.colour); //black
```